# How to connect Android Emulator with localhost:8012 configured with xamp on my computer?

Tags: android-emulator, xampp, localhost

I am facing trouble to connect emulator with localhost:8012. I tried replacing localhost with 10.0.2.2 and my ip address as well but no use. Can somebody guide me? is it because of the port I am facing trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, no matter what OS platform you have you have a mapping at the OS level that allows you set localhost to IP numbers and or a combination of localhost and port numbers.

so you have to amp that emulator IP to the other one. On all OS platforms its called a host file, by-the-way

see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: can you please explain with example. I am a novice